# Indefinite Integral procedure

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, substitution, gamma-distribution

Can anyone explain me this definite integral I got from a probability problem:

$\mathbf E[X] = 2\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2} dx$
   $[x^2 = z]$
$=\int_0^\infty z^{{3\over2}-1}e^{-z} dz$
$= \Gamma({3\over2})$
$= {{\sqrt{\pi}}\over2}$

What I want to understand is from the first line to the third line.
How did $2x^2$ become $z^{{3\over2}-1}$ with $x^2 = z$?
(Please ignore if there are grammatical errors).

Comment: $x^2=z$ implies that $x=z^{1/2}$, $dx=z^{-1/2}dz/2$. Hence $2x^2dx=z^{1/2}dz$

Comment: Thanks a lot...